# My iOS app has bigger tab bar, navigation bar and keyboard than other apps

Tags: ios, iphone

My app has bigger tab bar, navigation bar and keyboard than other apps. How can I change it? Here is the side by side screenshots of my app vs. other apps
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZJCx.jpg)

Comment: What are the resolutions supported by your app ? As if you're not supporting native resolution for a device, your app will be expanded to fit the device size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to required support for bigger size device means you have not added launch image for 6 & 6+ screen. so it scaled your screen automatically.

Comment: Please don't link to other answers, just close the question as a duplicate of the answer.